# Cannot decrypt data .net 6 with bare bones implementation keep getting The input data is not a complete block

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes

There are lots of topics on this but none of them seem to solve the problem.

So here is the code I am using, ive gone to a bare bones implementation which should work:

```
public class CustomEncryptor : IEncryptor
{
    public string Key { get; } // 32 bytes i.e 6GUNtgba8Rqgm5tc9JGhzxjN6XbzuyNM

    public CustomEncryptor(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }

    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data)
    {
        using var aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Key);
        aes.IV = RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(16);
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        return aes.EncryptCbc(data, aes.IV);
    }

    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data)
    {
        using var aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Key);
        aes.IV = RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(16);
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        return aes.DecryptCbc(data, aes.IV);
    }
}
```

It encrypts the data fine, but when I come to decrypt it I always get:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The input data is
> not a complete block.

Given I am using the aes built in methods and im providing a key of 32 bytes, then generating 16 bytes for the initialisation vector it should all be fine right, ive tried just giving it a blank `new byte[16]` instead and that doesn't help, I have also tried different padding modes and nothing works.

To give some context the app that uses this has an extension method it uses to simplify `string` scenarios, the use cases are often user does something, it encrypts it and saves it somewhere, then when the app is reloaded it decrypts it and puts it in a var for usage.

```
public static string Encrypt(this IEncryptor encryptor, string textToEncrypt)
{
    var textAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToEncrypt);
    var encryptedData = encryptor.Encrypt(textAsBytes);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
}

public static string Decrypt(this IEncryptor encryptor, string encryptedText)
{
    var textAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
    var decryptedData = encryptor.Decrypt(textAsBytes);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData);
}
```

I am baffled as to why it doesnt work as lots of examples online do same sort of thing.

== Update 1 ==

It was mentioned in comments that the key & iv need to be consistent so I have tried setting that to explicitly be the same thing like so:

```
public class CustomEncryptor : IEncryptor
{
    public byte[] Key { get; }
    public byte[] IV { get; }

    public CustomEncryptor(byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {        
        IV = iv;
        Key = key;
    }
    
    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data)
    {
        using var aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Key = Key;
        return aes.EncryptCbc(data, IV);
    }

    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data)
    {
        using var aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Key = Key;
        return aes.DecryptCbc(data, IV);
    }
}

// Example usage
var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("UxRBN8hfjzTG86d6SkSSNzyUhERGu5Zj"); // 32 bytes
var iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("7cA8jkRMJGZ8iMeJ"); // 16 bytes
services.AddSingleton<IEncryptor>(new CustomEncryptor(key, iv));
```

Still get same error

Comment: For decryption, the **same** IV must be used as for encryption (your implementation applies different IVs). For this, usually the *random* IV is concatenated with the ciphertext (iv|ciphertext) and separated on the decrypting side (the disclosure of the IV is not a problem since the IV is not secret).

Comment: Note also that using 32 ASCII characters doesn't make for a very good key -- with about 6 bits per character this offers only 192 bits of entropy for a 256-bit key. A Base64 representation of that (if printable characters are desired) would also be readable and only 12 characters longer. If on the other hand a "readable" key must be used as the input, use a proper key derivation function.

Comment: Ah ok I didnt know the IV needed to be the same, thanks for confirming that for me, and for the moment the key is completely user configurable so they could provide a byte array in the real world if they wanted to.

Comment: @Topaco I have just tried this and getting same error, I will add an update to main ticket showing changes, but same error even with same key and iv each time.

Comment: Try producing a [mre]. What you have now isn't it -- in particular, you haven't eliminated the possibility that the data to be decrypted hasn't been mangled somehow.

Comment: I cannot get this to happen within a unit test scenario, but for some reason when the app restarts even though its hard coded currently to give it the same key for me to work on this issue it seems to be not passing but I cannot think of a way to simulate that within a unit test, ive even tried making 2 different instances within the test with same key and iv. I will see if I can try to isolate what could be different there.

Comment: haha so turns out im 1000% an idiot as it was reading an incorrect variable on rehydration, so thats why it wasnt working, BUT even if that wasnt the case the IV was different each time which would have caused an issue, so if you want to put that as the answer im happy to accept it @Topaco

Comment: If you’re using the new EncryptCbc (and friends) methods there’s no reason to set the IV or Padding properties. Those methods only use the Key property (and the algorithm) outside their parameters.